# Removing Non Unicode characters from a file

Tags: python-2.7, ascii, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode, non-unicode

I know this is  repeated question but I have really tried hard all of the solutions so far. Can anyone please help how to get rid of chacracters like \xc3\xa2\xc2\x84\xc2\xa2 from a file?

The file content which I am trying to clean currently is:
b'Roasted Onion Dip',"b""['2 pounds large yellow onions, thinly sliced', '3 large shallots, thinly sliced', '4 sprigs thyme', '1/4 cup olive oil', 'Kosher salt and freshly ground black pepper', '1 cup white wine', '2 tablespoons champagne vinegar', '2 cups sour cream', '1/2 cup chopped fresh chives', '1/4 cup plain Greek yogurt', 'Everything seasoning and thyme to garnish', 'Cape Cod Waves\xc3\xa2\xc2\x84\xc2\xa2 Potato Chips for serving']"""

I have tried using re.sub('[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ',whatevertext) but can't seem to get anywhere. I suspect that \ here is not being treated as a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> f = open("test.txt","r")
>>> whatevertext = f.read()
>>> print whatevertext
b'Roasted Onion Dip',"b""['2 pounds large yellow onions, thinly sliced', '3 large shallots, thinly sliced', '4 sprigs thyme', '1/4 cup olive oil', 'Kosher salt and freshly ground black pepper', '1 cup white wine', '2 tablespoons champagne vinegar', '2 cups sour cream', '1/2 cup chopped fresh chives', '1/4 cup plain Greek yogurt', 'Everything seasoning and thyme to garnish', 'Cape Cod Waves\xc3\xa2\xc2\x84\xc2\xa2 Potato Chips for serving']"""

>>> import re
>>> result = re.sub('\\\\x[a-f|0-9]+','',whatevertext)
>>> print result
b'Roasted Onion Dip',"b""['2 pounds large yellow onions, thinly sliced', '3 large shallots, thinly sliced', '4 sprigs thyme', '1/4 cup olive oil', 'Kosher salt and freshly ground black pepper', '1 cup white wine', '2 tablespoons champagne vinegar', '2 cups sour cream', '1/2 cup chopped fresh chives', '1/4 cup plain Greek yogurt', 'Everything seasoning and thyme to garnish', 'Cape Cod Waves Potato Chips for serving']"""

>>>
```

'\\x[a-f|0-9]+' in this regex, each slash is escaped with a slash and after x we know that there can be either numbers from 0-9 or alphabets from a-f.

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot!